# System.IObserver'1<T0> is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, reference

I have checked some code out of source control and am getting the following error when I try to build:

> The type 'System.IObserver`1' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Observable, Version=1.0.0.204, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

So first port of call was to Google. Looks like I need the Rx Framework. So I downloaded the [Reactive Extensions experimental release](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577610). I installed it completely, closed VS2010 SP1, and then went back in. Getting the same error.

What else could I need to do?

Comment: Did you try adding the reference that it asks for?

Comment: You installed it, but did you add the assembly as a reference in your project?

Comment: `System.IObservable<T>` was added to MSCORLIB in .NET 4. Earlier pre-release (at least) Rx versions supported earlier versions of .NET. What version of .NET is the project targeting?

Comment: @Richard: `IObserver<T>` is not the same as `IObservable<T>`!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth oops: typo. Replace with `System.IObserver<T>` and still applies.

Comment: @Richard: I don't follow. There is a [`System.IObserver<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx) in .NET4 but it lives in mscorlib.dll and not in `System.Observable` as the exception indicates. He clearly needs the Rx version of this interface.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Please re-read the whole of my first question. Noting these interfaces are *now* in MSCORLIB is the introduction. The real comment is the question at the end, because I suspect the project is targeting 2/3/3.5 and thus need the corresponding Rx (and I can't recall if pre-.NET 4 was dropped for Rx 1.0).

Comment: I target .NET 4.5... Resintalled RxMain NuGet... Didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

As the message says, your project needs to reference the System.Observable assembly. Simply installing the Rx framework doesn't add a reference to your project...

Comment: there is no such a library. At least, Visual Studio 2013 didn't find it for a project targeting .NET 4.5

Comment: I added, but nothing changed. The same message. Finally, I found in a old project the "System.Observable.dll", and added manually that reference.

Comment: @Serge You are right: As in the comments to the question itself: System.Observable.dll no longer exists. Depending on the version of `IObserver` you need, it is either in MSCORLIB or in System.Reactive.dll. Most likely, you are seeing this error in your project, because you are referencing a library, that was built against a very old version of the reactive extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You've installed the required extensions, but you'll still need to add it as a reference within your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading from NuGet.  Right click, "Manage NuGet"... Search Online for "Rx_Exper.."

http://nuget.org/packages/Rx_Experimental-Silverlight/1.1.11111

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio

- Right-click the References folder of your project
- Click Add reference...
- In the Add Reference window, choose from Assemblies >> Extensions
- Click System.Observable from the list
- Click Add

Problem solved

Comment: there is no such a library. .NET 4.5